# RxAndroid - Supporting background App behavior usecases

Tags: android, rx-java, background-process, rx-android

I am developing an android app which, for most part is a background app except for one activity. The activity won't be launched that often and is mainly used for controlling various settings.

The background behavior will mostly be triggered based on various system broadcasts as well as by other means such as content observer callbacks and such (ofcourse, for content observer callbacks process has to be running). The work that has to be carried out as a result of such triggers is a set of ordered work, that at the end of execution can trigger other workstream such as that of writing data to disk for example.

I've been looking at various articles & documentation around RxJava and RxAndroid but was unable to conclude on how I am able to make use of RxJava/RxAndroid.

As an example, third party libraries like that of RxBroadcastReceiver and RxBroadcast seems to be only useful when the application process is running. I.e. the application has to register itself to listen for system/application broadcasts as observer and upon receiving such, work can be carried out through subscription.

But, given for my case the application won't be running all the time and that the broadcast has to be registered by means of android manifest, I am not sure how I can make use of RxJava/RxAndroid, if at all.

Appreciate some help here as I am pretty much new to RxJava/RxAndroid to begin with.

Comment: What you *should* check is if you actually receive those broadcasts if registered via manifest since the background process limitations introduced in nougat/oreo

Comment: You should read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to understand what kind of questions you should avoid asking!